# How to set a chrono DateTime to a specific date and time?

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

I need to create a `chrono::DateTime<Local>` instance that is set to a specific date and time. For example, I need to create a `DateTime<Local>` instance that is set to something like 3/17/2019 at 4:43 PM (or 3/17/2019 at 16:43).

The documentation for the `DateTime` struct shows how to get the current date and time via the `now` function and plenty of support for getting time durations. There appears to be some confusing traits and conversion functions, but there doesn't appear to be anything that allows me to directly create a `DateTime` instance that represents a specific date and time.

Is it possible to create such an instance? If so, how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a function called [`ymd`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.ymd) for the `TimeZone` trait that returns a date. You can then call [`and_hms`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/struct.Date.html#method.and_hms) on this date to set a specific time.

```
use chrono::TimeZone;
let dt = chrono::Local.ymd(2019, 3, 17).and_hms(16, 43, 0);
```