# Create a chrono::DateTime for tests

Tags: rust

This question is related to this existing question:

[How to set a Chrono Datetime to a Specific Data and Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214065/how-to-set-a-chrono-datetime-to-a-specific-date-and-time)

The methods suggested in the answer are deprecated. It is suggested to use `with_ymd_and_hms` instead.

https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.with_ymd_and_hms

However, this returns an enum. If a result type was returned, this could have been relatively easy to use by calling `unwrap`. But it doesn't.

I want an easy way to build a `chrono::DateTime` object for use with unit tests, with a method which isn't depricated. How can I do that? (Without parsing a string.)

## Why no parse from strings?

Try reading this in a test:

`DateTime:: parse_from_rfc3339("2023-7-1T00:00:00-00:00");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest calling `with_ymd_and_hms`

https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.with_ymd_and_hms

And then calling `unwrap` from `LocalResult`

https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/enum.LocalResult.html#method.unwrap

So it is almost the same as enum type `Result<T,E>`

Example tested on a cargo project:

```rust
use chrono::offset::TimeZone;
use chrono::offset::Utc;
use chrono::DateTime;

fn main() {
    // for UTC timezone
    let datetime: DateTime<Utc> = Utc.with_ymd_and_hms(2023, 7, 19, 13, 10, 0).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", datetime);
}
```